# Engagement Split not treating Clicks correctly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Why would Engagement Split in my journey treat clicks on 'Update Profile' link as successful ? I have 2 links in my email (both have aliases)
  - update Profile
  - download PDF link from the portfolio items

The split activity has the download pdf link configured but it always counts the click on 'Update Profile' and sends the subscriber to a wrong path

I have read several posts but couldn't find a concrete solution (except for writing query on Click data view). Is that still the only solution?

Comment: Is the Update Profile link an ampscript link?

If so, engagement link tracking does NOT work on dynamic links:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKNqQAM

They need to be static links to evaluate for a click.